# How to choose the relative sizes of training and validation sets?

Tags: machine-learning, sampling, data-mining, validation, partitioning

When I work with the methods of data mining, the data is split in training and validations data samples (and sometimes test). I know training + validation = 100%. Which criteria can I use to find a good proportion for training and validation? Does it depend on the data sample size?

Comment: random partitioning is often used

Answer (score 1):

Split-sample validation requires enormous samples sizes to work as detailed in [RMS](https://hbiostat.org/rms) and [BBR](https://hbiostat.org/bbr).  Depending on the signal:noise ratio the minimum sample size may be more than 20,000 independent samples.  This is because the analysis is too dependent on the luck of the split, i.e., if you split again you'll easily get different models and different validation indexes.  All this is why resampling (bootstrap or 100 repeats of 10-fold cross-validation) are so popular.  And they validate the *process* used to build the model, not just a final example model, if any feature selection or tuning is going on.  Detailed case studies may be found in the RMS Course Notes linked above.

Answer (score 0):

Typically one uses proportion $70\%$ to training and $30\%$ to validation.

The reason behind this is the following: using a testing procedure you want to estimate a performance of algorithm A for a sample size $n$.

- If you keep too small number of objects for training, you get estimate of performance of algorithm A at sample size $c n$ with $c$ small - so you will add negative bias to your estimate.
- But of you keep too small amount of data for validation then you will get big variance in estimates as quality will depend on small number of objects selected for validation. To remove variance you can use cross-validation - numerous splits to training and validation sets with averaging of the result.

So, empirical rules like the one described above try to find a tradeoff between bias and variance of algorithm performance estimate.

Note, that also in many cases you will need to perform specific split. For example, you can split data with stratification: for training and validations sets shares of a first class objects are the same.